# Write excel using excel package with formatting

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, excelpackage

I want to write excel file using excel package from `System.Data.DataTable`

and need to format some cells in excel file like back ground color.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did not the samples in the project's home page help? What is it exactly that you can't do?

Comment: Go through it...[How to format an Excel file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm) **EDIT:** Or If you want to do this without using then refer this: [Format an Excel File without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) Or [CSharp Excel Library](http://e-infotainment.com/applications/csharp-excel-library/)

Comment: have a look at my question @Lajja Thaker - which comes without use of Interop!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz yes but it does not gives me any idea regarding formatting

Comment: completly rewrote my answer - now hope it meets your requirements!

Answer (score 9):

Although you may use **Interop** calls to create an excel file, I **prefer solutions without** it. According to your given details I found a solution based on **OpenXML**. No need for Interop but you *have to learn the according objectModel* from openXML. What you need before you can start:

1. **Download OpenXML SDK** and install it from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)
2. Go to [openXmlDeveloper.org](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) and **learn how to use openXml** to create excelFiles
3. Have a look at several ressources in the web concerning how to access/read/write excelFiles with openXml (such as [SO_Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117013/adding-multiple-cells-to-a-single-row), [social.msdn.microsoft.com_example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/a973335c-9f9b-4e70-883a-02a0bcff43d2), [Blog1](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm) and [SO_Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012547/creating-excel-document-with-openxml-sdk-2-0))

Afterwards within your project...

4. Add reference to *DocumentFormat.OpenXML* library (search your computer, somewhat like *C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.0\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll*)
5. Add reference to *WindowBase*

And than you are ready to use this piece of code:

```
// important namespaces
using System.IO.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using Excel = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Excel;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // created a demoTable with id column and five string columns with arbitrary values
    DataTable demoTable = CreateDemoTable();
    CreateWorkbook(@"c:\ExcelAndStyles.xlsx", demoTable);
}
private static void CreateWorkbook(string fileName, DataTable table)
{            
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            File.Delete(fileName);

        using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart wbp = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
            WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
            fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";

            Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();
            WorkbookStylesPart wbsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            // add styles to sheet
            wbsp.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet();
            wbsp.Stylesheet.Save();

            // generate data (row&cells) and add it to workbook
            SheetData sd = CreateSheetData(table);
            ws.Append(sd);
            wsp.Worksheet = ws;
            wsp.Worksheet.Save();

            Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
            sheet.Name = table.TableName;
            sheet.SheetId = 1;
            sheet.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            wb.Append(fv);
            wb.Append(sheets);

            xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
            xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            xl.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { // do some errorHandling here  }
}
private static Stylesheet CreateStylesheet()
{
    // add namespace info
    Stylesheet stylesheet1 = new Stylesheet() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "x14ac" } };
    stylesheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
    stylesheet1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14ac", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac");

    // fonts
    Fonts fonts1 = new Fonts() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U, KnownFonts = true };

    Font font1 = new Font();
    FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize() { Val = 11D };
    Color color1 = new Color() { Theme = (UInt32Value)1U };
    FontName fontName1 = new FontName() { Val = "Calibri" };
    FontFamilyNumbering fontFamilyNumbering1 = new FontFamilyNumbering() { Val = 2 };
    FontScheme fontScheme1 = new FontScheme() { Val = FontSchemeValues.Minor };

    font1.Append(fontSize1);
    font1.Append(color1);
    font1.Append(fontName1);
    font1.Append(fontFamilyNumbering1);
    font1.Append(fontScheme1);

    fonts1.Append(font1);

    // fillColor 
    Fills fills1 = new Fills() { Count = (UInt32Value)5U };

    // FillId = 0
    Fill fill1 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill1 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None };
    fill1.Append(patternFill1);

    // FillId = 1
    Fill fill2 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill2 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 };
    fill2.Append(patternFill2);

    // FillId = 2,RED
    Fill fill3 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill3 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
    ForegroundColor foregroundColor1 = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FFFF0000" };
    BackgroundColor backgroundColor1 = new BackgroundColor() { Indexed = (UInt32Value)64U };
    patternFill3.Append(foregroundColor1);
    patternFill3.Append(backgroundColor1);
    fill3.Append(patternFill3);

    // FillId = 3,BLUE
    Fill fill4 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill4 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
    ForegroundColor foregroundColor2 = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FF0070C0" };
    BackgroundColor backgroundColor2 = new BackgroundColor() { Indexed = (UInt32Value)64U };
    patternFill4.Append(foregroundColor2);
    patternFill4.Append(backgroundColor2);
    fill4.Append(patternFill4);

    // FillId = 4,YELLO
    Fill fill5 = new Fill();
    PatternFill patternFill5 = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
    ForegroundColor foregroundColor3 = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FFFFFF00" };
    BackgroundColor backgroundColor3 = new BackgroundColor() { Indexed = (UInt32Value)64U };
    patternFill5.Append(foregroundColor3);
    patternFill5.Append(backgroundColor3);
    fill5.Append(patternFill5);

    fills1.Append(fill1); // 0U
    fills1.Append(fill2); // 1U
    fills1.Append(fill3); // 2U
    fills1.Append(fill4); // 3U
    fills1.Append(fill5); // 4U

    // border styles
    Borders borders1 = new Borders() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };

    Border border1 = new Border();
    LeftBorder leftBorder1 = new LeftBorder();
    RightBorder rightBorder1 = new RightBorder();
    TopBorder topBorder1 = new TopBorder();
    BottomBorder bottomBorder1 = new BottomBorder();
    DiagonalBorder diagonalBorder1 = new DiagonalBorder();

    border1.Append(leftBorder1);
    border1.Append(rightBorder1);
    border1.Append(topBorder1);
    border1.Append(bottomBorder1);
    border1.Append(diagonalBorder1);

    borders1.Append(border1);

    // cellFormats
    CellStyleFormats cellStyleFormats1 = new CellStyleFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
    CellFormat cellFormat1 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U };
    cellStyleFormats1.Append(cellFormat1);

    CellFormats cellFormats1 = new CellFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)4U };
    // see a few lines above - refer to: fills1.Append(XXXX);
    // see also ApplyFill = true!!
    CellFormat cellFormat2 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)0U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U };
    CellFormat cellFormat3 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)2U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyFill = true };
    CellFormat cellFormat4 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)3U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyFill = true };
    CellFormat cellFormat5 = new CellFormat() { NumberFormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, FontId = (UInt32Value)0U, FillId = (UInt32Value)4U, BorderId = (UInt32Value)0U, FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, ApplyFill = true };

    cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat2); // fillId 0U    ---  cellFormat Index 0
    cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat3); // fillId 2U    ---  cellFormat Index 1
    cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat4); // fillId 3U    ---  cellFormat Index 2
    cellFormats1.Append(cellFormat5); // fillId 4U    ---  cellFormat Index 3

    // cellStyles
    CellStyles cellStyles1 = new CellStyles() { Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
    CellStyle cellStyle1 = new CellStyle() { Name = "Normal", FormatId = (UInt32Value)0U, BuiltinId = (UInt32Value)0U };
    cellStyles1.Append(cellStyle1);

    DifferentialFormats differentialFormats1 = new DifferentialFormats() { Count = (UInt32Value)0U };
    TableStyles tableStyles1 = new TableStyles() { Count = (UInt32Value)0U, DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2", DefaultPivotStyle = "PivotStyleMedium9" };

    // extensions
    StylesheetExtensionList stylesheetExtensionList1 = new StylesheetExtensionList();

    StylesheetExtension stylesheetExtension1 = new StylesheetExtension() { Uri = "{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}" };
    stylesheetExtension1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("x14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main");
    Excel.SlicerStyles slicerStyles1 = new Excel.SlicerStyles() { DefaultSlicerStyle = "SlicerStyleLight1" };
    stylesheetExtension1.Append(slicerStyles1);

    stylesheetExtensionList1.Append(stylesheetExtension1);

    // add all formats/styles to stylesheet
    stylesheet1.Append(fonts1);
    stylesheet1.Append(fills1);
    stylesheet1.Append(borders1);
    stylesheet1.Append(cellStyleFormats1);
    stylesheet1.Append(cellFormats1);
    stylesheet1.Append(cellStyles1);
    stylesheet1.Append(differentialFormats1);
    stylesheet1.Append(tableStyles1);
    stylesheet1.Append(stylesheetExtensionList1);
    return stylesheet1;
}
private static SheetData CreateSheetData(DataTable table)
{
    SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();            
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        DataRow dataRow = table.Rows[rowIndex];
        Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = new UInt32Value((uint)(rowIndex + 1)) };
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; colIndex++)
        {
            object value = dataRow[colIndex].ToString();

            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.CellReference = ((char)(colIndex + 65)).ToString() + (rowIndex+1).ToString();
            // assigned simple red background style
            // have a deeper look in CreateStylesheet for details what 1U contains
            // for demo purposes may choose 2U and 3U too
            cell.StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U;
            // for demo purposes, treat all values as string  
            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(table.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString());
            row.Append(cell);
        }
        sheetData.Append(row);
    }
    return sheetData;
}
```

Most of this code has been **taken out of several sites** listed above! I adopted it and changed it to fit your question. This example code worked for me to create an *excelFile* containing *several rows and columns* with *differen values and styles*.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why the downvote - please let me know, so I can improve my answer!